# Не получается удалять элементы из базы данных SQLite с помощью имени

Tags: java, android, база-данных, sqlite, delete

Есть база данных:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userstore.db"; // название бд
    private static final int SCHEMA = 5; // версия базы данных
    static final String TABLE = "users"; // название таблицы в бд
    // названия столбцов
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_NUMBER = "number";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA); //создание безы данных и передача ей названия и номера версии
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // создание таблицы и добавление в неё столбцов
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE users (" + COLUMN_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," //создание id и обеспечение уникальности каждого id
                + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " //создание текстового столбца
                + COLUMN_NUMBER + " TEXT);"); //создание числового столбца
        // добавление начальных данных
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ TABLE +" (" + COLUMN_NAME
                + ", " + COLUMN_NUMBER  + ") VALUES ('Том Смит', 8800);");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,  int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE); //обновление таблицы
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

В активности я пытаюсь удалить из неё строку, с помощью имени (COLUMN_NAME):

```
  .......

    case R.id.btnDel:
                if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    break;
                }
                int delCount = database.delete(DatabaseHelper.TABLE, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + " = ?", new String[] {name});

                Log.d("mLog", "deleted rows count = " + delCount);
        }
        databaseHelper.close();
```

Но, по какой-то причине это не работает, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить

Comment: `if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("")) { break}` id  здесь у вас это что?

Comment: @Z.John, спасибо, не заметил)